# Collaborative Konva canvas

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, konvajs

I am making a konva whiteboard in React. I want it to be a collaborative whiteboard, meaning I want to be able to connect with other users on different pc's to use the whiteboard together. I know that HTML5 canvas works with socket-io, is it also possible with konva canvas? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Konva should be fine for a collaborative whiteboard app. Konva is only a wrapper around Canvas. The collaborative aspect is going to be more a networking and data handling problem separate from Konva. You may also want to look into [webrtc](https://webrtc.org/) for the collaborative aspect although it may not be necessary.